# MvvmCross Dependency Injection Cannot Resolve the Type with .net core ILogger

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, mvvmcross

I am using `MvvmCross 7.0.0 version` to building an `WPF application`, which I need to use a class library `(.net standard 2.0)` for dependency injection for my WPF application.

In the `.core project App` File Initialize method, I configured the DI as below:

```
Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType<ITestService,TestService>();
Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ITestService>();
```

But it caused me the exception, when I run the application:

> MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: 'Failed to resolve
> parameter for parameter logger of type ILogger when creating
> TextExtractor.Core.TestService. You may pass it as an argument'

I think it must be the problem I am using the ILogger in the constructor in that class library method.

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TestService(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public string Run()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Run");
        return "HelloWorldFROMrUN!";
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to figured out how to fix this issue?
I do need to use the `ILogger` in the  TestService function for logging purpose, when I was building a Blazor project, I can just inject `ILogger` and `IConfiguration` in `W/O` any issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you registered an implementation of `ILogger` with the container before you try to resolve `ITestService`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay that can be my second question, how to do that?